# How can I get a button click event to fire as soon as my page loads?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got this jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("body").on( "click", "#btnGetData", function() {
        var _begdate = $("#datepickerFrom").val();
        var _enddate = $("#datepickerTo").val();
        var _unit = $("#unitName").text();
        document.body.style.cursor = 'wait';

        $.ajax({
            . . .elided for brevity.
        });
    });
    $("#btnGenData").trigger('click');
});
```

I need the click event to occur as soon as the page load; I tried calling it this way, after the click function:

```
$("#btnGenData").trigger('click');
```

...but it doesn't work. What am I missing?

Comment: Enter your code directly  to page load event :)

Comment: @cale_b: It does get added dynamically the second and subsequent times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The click handler is looking for any button that is a child of the body with an id of btn**Get**Data. The id of the button you are triggering is btn**Gen**Data.

Comment: dang, I love those typos.

Comment: Its an especially tough one because not only is the typo an actual word, they are practically synonyms.

Answer (score 0):

Although you problem is because of a small typosince First line must have id `#btnGenData` instead is `#btnGetData` but apart from it I would recommend you to use setTimeout in document.ready to trigger the click event. A delay of 10ms will cause the function to run immediately after all the `$(document).ready()` handlers have been called.

```
**$("body").on( "click", "#btnGetData", function()** {
        var _begdate = $("#datepickerFrom").val();
        var _enddate = $("#datepickerTo").val();
        var _unit = $("#unitName").text();
        document.body.style.cursor = 'wait';

        $.ajax({
            . . .elided for brevity.
        });
    });
```

```js
$(function(){
  setTimeout(function() {
        $("#btnGenData").trigger('click');
    },10);
    
  $('#btnGenData').on('click', function(){
    alert('clicked');
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="btnGenData">btnCick</div>
```